# circuitikz, battery symbol changes

Tags: circuitikz

When I make a simple circuit containing a cell with to[battery2, V=$1.5V$] and a resistor (R), I get the circle for the battery symbol:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[battery2, V=$1.5V$] (0,2)
to[short, i=$I_0$] (2,2)
to[R] (2,0)
to[short] (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

If I leave out the info for the battery and just use to[battery2], I get the battery symbol consisting of the long and short bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[battery2] (0,2)
to[short, i=$I_0$] (2,2)
to[R] (2,0)
to[short] (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Why is my battery symbol changing?  I want to keep the long and short bar symbol for my battery.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!  You should use `[battery2, v=$1.5V$]` (`V` is wrong, it call symbol for voltage generator).

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew it was something trivial! (but not a trivial result.)

Comment: Notice that `$1.5V$` really means 1.5 multiplied by the variable *V*. If you want to say "1.5 volts", better use `\qty{1.5}{V}` with the `siunitx` package (print both side to side and observe the difference!).

Answer (score 2):

Let me spell out my comment to an answer ...

- With `V` is designate `european voltages source` (see 4.5.2 Stationary sources, page 63 and note in frame on page 64)
- `v` indicate voltage drop over pasive elements (R, C, L) or generated voltage at voltage source
- If two you write two elements in path options as you do in MWE (Minimal Working Example) in your question, prevail the last one.

Correct code for your circuit scheme is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [battery2, v=$1.5V$] (0,2)
            to[short, i=$I_0$] (2,2)
            to[R] (2,0)
            to[short] (0,0)
            ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good answer, you explain *why* the OP's code is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use features available in `tikz package` as

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [battery2, l=1.5<\volt>, invert] (0,2)
    to [short, i=$I_0$] (2,2)
    to [R] (2,0)
    to (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Even the environment `circuitikz` can be changed into that of `tikzpicture' for the same output as

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [battery2, l=1.5<\volt>, invert] (0,2)
    to [short, i=$I_0$] (2,2)
    to [R] (2,0)
    to (0,0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `circuitikz` and `tikzpicture` are *always* exactly the same... historical thing. I am thinking of removing `circuitikz` from the manual altogether.  As a side note, the special `siunitx` syntax is not really robust, I suggest using `l=\SI{1.5}{\volt}` (or `l=\qty[1.5}{\volt}` with `siunitx` v3).